# How to authenticate using SSL cert instead of user/password via JMX connection to ActiveMQ Artemis?

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

I connect via JMX to a broker. I connect using user/password. Now I need to connect via SSL (certificate). How and where can I attach a certificate so that I can connect via SSL? I know that I need to configure the trustStore and keyStore, but I don't understand how I can choose the certificate that I need and enclose it

I am attaching my code for connecting via jmx user/password:

```java
public static MBeanServerConnection connectBroker(String brokerUrl, String login, String password) {
    MBeanServerConnection mBeanServerConnection = null;
    try {
        Map<String, String[]> env = new HashMap();
        String[] creds = {login, password};
        env.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, creds);
        JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://" + brokerUrl + "/jmxrmi"), env);
        mBeanServerConnection = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
        DialogsAlert.brokerJmxRmiConnectionSuccess.showAndWait();
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,"success" + brokerUrl);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING,"fail", e);
    }
    return mBeanServerConnection;
}
```

The certificate will be allowed to be in the folder with the project

Comment: Any update here? Did you get this sorted?

Comment: Did the answer here address your question? If so, can you mark it as correct to help others who have this same question in the future? If not, can you elaborate on what exactly you figured out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis supports a JMX connector with SSL, see the [jmx-ssl](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/2.30.0/examples/features/standard/jmx-ssl) example. However the JMX connections are only authenticated via user/password, you cannot use a certificate to authenticate a JMX connection.

Comment: That is, if I want to use the JMX protocol and use a certificate for user authentication via ssl, then nothing will come of it, since there is no such thing in JMX? Are there any workarounds? Use JMS?

Comment: JMX and JMS are not simply interchangeable. Whether or not you can do equivalent work with JMS depends on your specific use-case, although you didn't explain your specific use-case in the question.

Comment: We use JMX because JMX has the ability to read the headers as they came before the defect. Therefore, the solution is built on JMX

Comment: In the oracle documentation, I found this phrase: Note - For production systems, use both SSL client certificates to authenticate the client host and password authentication for user management. See the topics Using SSL and Using LDAP Authentication for more information. Doesn't it say that I can do certificate authentication?

In the case of my code, where should I go or what can I do?

Comment: and isn't here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017686/active-mq-jmx-ssl trying to connect to activemq ssl by jmx?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017686/active-mq-jmx-ssl is for ActiveMQ Classic. The JaasAuthenticator used by ActiveMQ Artemis to authenticate JMX connections only supports user/password callbacks, see https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/2.30.0/artemis-server/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/server/management/JaasAuthenticator.java#L61

Comment: I believe the client "authentication" with SSL referred to in the Oracle documentation is merely the _verification_ that the client is who it says it is provided by its possession of the certificate. This is, in fact, one of the main benefits of SSL although it's typically reserved for clients "authenticating" the identity of the server. The Oracle documentation clearly indicates that this should be _combined_ with password authentication rather than replacing it like you are trying to do.